# Can't unbind event from an input element in knockout framework

Tags: knockout.js

I have an input input element like this

```
<input id="txtId" type="text" data-bind="value: query, valueUpdate: 'keyup'">
```

and also I have a collection that bind to this input

```js
<script>
         var terms = [{name: blah,...,... }];

         var viewModel = { query: ko.observable('') };

         viewModel.terms = ko.dependentObservable(function () {

                var search = this.query().toLowerCase();                       

                return ko.utils.arrayFilter(terms, function (term) 
                {
                    return term.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0;
                });

            }, viewModel);  

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

I want to choice available items and they should appear in my input element. But item bind with collection and collection begin to change. I need somehow to break bindings. So help please)

Comment: It sounds like you really want a <select> element.  Is this correct?

Comment: Initially I have bound input element with a collection. Then I am trying to change the collection and with the collection changes the input. The question is I want to change input without changing collection. Maybe it sounds little bit stupid)) but it is a task) thanks for your replies.

Comment: Interesting problem.  However, KO doesn't allow you to bind an array to a value type binding.  Your dependentObservable can only return a single value to work with your data binding.  Would an auto-complete input work?  If yes, there is a solution for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved that question. I have created a flag (ability to modify collection) this class is not observable and with it I can manipulate my collection)